# In Visual Studio (not VS Code!), how can I hide the tabs panel?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I hide the tabs panel in my Visual Studio? I do not need it. See the image.

[image]

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Set tab layout > Top/Left/Right

Comment: You could always try Jetbrains' Rider that allows a tabless experience - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND0Br0jMl7M.

Comment: Would be great if Visual Studio had a tab layout of left/right/top/bottom and none, maybe in a future release of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not possible to hide it. I have just placed it to the "top" position. That is is easy and, as a result, the tab panel stoped taking too much space on my screen.

Comment: If the tab bar were completely hidden, how would you switch between documents?

Comment: You can use `Edit`->`Go To`->`Go To Recent File...` or assign a shortcut to it.